# extracting number using regular expression

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I want to extract the number '123' from this:

```
<div class="f_right" style="padding-top:5px;">123</div>
```

What regular expression should I use? How can I extract just the number, without the wrapping `<div>`?

Comment: [Don't use regex when dealing with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Please explain what environment you are in. What programming language di you use, where does the HTML come from?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what situations you're wanting to match numbers in. The regular expression `/123/` will extract the number 123 from that string, but I doubt that's what you're after. Similarly, `/<div class="f_right" style="padding-top:5px;">(...)/` will extract 123, but that's probably not going to catch many of the situations you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dario is right but if you want to do it this might work:

For yahoo pipes it should be like this.

```
<div class=".*?" style=".*?">(\d+)<\/div>
```

`$1` will be your match

Comment: Don't forget to escape the slash - `</div>` -> `<\/div>`, then it is at at least passable. `:)`

Comment: Thank you :). It should have been escaped :(

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I am using Yahoo Pipes, but its not giving me '123' but the entire string again, btw i am using $1 for (\d+) for match

Comment: works for me: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=f00101993e2589ad703e3d54ca3058e7&_render=json . Make sure to ignore  / at the beginning and end of the regex when using in yahoo pipes. Updated the regex to be usable on Yahoo